# Notice: Undefined index userkullanici

Tags: php, indexing, notice

i tried so many solution but its not work can anybody help me ?

```
$kullanicisor=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kullanici where kullanici_mail=:mail");
$kullanicisor->execute(array(
    'mail' => $_SESSION['userkullanici_mail']
));
```

help please.

Comment: As the error says, the index is not set.

Comment: `$_SESSION['userkullanici_mail']` is not defined, define it